Are $i^\pm$ and $i^0$ codimension 1 surfaces?
Standard textbooks like Carroll's say that spatial and temporal infinities in Minkowski space Penrose diagram are points. But on the footnote in pg. 3 of some draft notes on Celestial holography by  PSE's own Dr. Prahar Mitra, it is claimed (quite reasonably perhaps) that these points are codimension 1 surfaces just like null infinities although with different topology. Is this something which is in tension with the current understanding of Penrose diagrams, some subtlety perhaps or is Prahar talking about something else altogether?

Penrose diagrams are a diagrammatic representation of the conformal compactification of a manifold, not of the manifold itself. The compactification part is required so we can draw the manifold on a finite-sized sheet of paper.
In the conformal compactification of Minkowski spacetime, $i^0$ and $i^\pm$ are codimension two hypersurfaces (so they appear as points in the Penrose diagram). However, in Minkowski spacetime itself, they are codimension one hypersurfaces.

Thanks for the answer. But does these "points at infinity" at all belong to the Minkowski space which is supposed to have no boundary?

The points at infinity do not belong to Minkowski space. The asymptotic boundaries of Minkowski space are defined via limits.

In the usual presentation of conformal compactification of Minkowski space, $i^\pm$ are points, not codimension 2 manifolds.


Are $i^\pm$ and $i^0$ codimension 1 surfaces?

Yes. But one should be careful to make a distinction between statements about temporal and spatial infinities as sets of “ideal points” of spacetime and images of same in an “unphysical space” of conformal compactification, and Penrose diagrams are pictorial representations of conformal compactification. Conformal compactification is useful for resolving null infinities but is singular at spacelike and timelike infinities, so if you need to do calculations there, you should choose another formalism.
I would recommend a figure from this paper as illustration of various infinities:

The “puzzle piece”, as it is called in caption, is defined by $|r^2-t^2|<\mathcal T$ and $r<\mathcal R$. It provides a good way to visualize all five infinities at once since they correspond to components of puzzle piece boundary. Note, that under conformal compactification the timelike and spacelike components of its boundary collapse to points as $\mathcal R,\mathcal T\to\infty$ as seen in this figure (taken from the same paper):

